# SpannableString not set in textview in oreo in android

Tags: android, string

I set text view data from SpannableString. It works correct. But when I press back button from another activity text view not shown data in Oreo. It works correctly in other version but not work in high version. What is reason?

Here my code for set data:

```
tvItinerari=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_1);

 String text = "";
    String name = "";
    for (Itinerary item : arrayList) {
        text += item.getItinerary()+"   ";

    }

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);


    int start = 0, end;
    for (final Itinerary item : arrayList) {
        setSpanOnLink(ss, item.getItinerary(), new MyClickableSpan(item));
    }

    tvItinerari.setText(ss);
    Log.e("ss",""+ss);
```

It works in all version not in Oreo.

Data show correctly in low version like lollipop but not work in High version.

Comment: Are you using a `shared element` transition when you navigate between `Activities`?

Comment: i do this code in fragment but also not working in activity

Comment: i am facing same issue

Comment: i set my string from array list so when i open fragment from back button my list null so text view not showing data please check your list because SpannableString has not any issue in Oreo @Vasu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check arrayList size  i think its zero when you back your activity.